# How to add an action to dispatch instead of the url in effect when using redux-offline

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-offline

I am using "redux-offline" to make my application work offline. I want to dispatch an action in the effect part and get the back end result to the commit part.

```
meta: {
        offline: {
                effect: { type: "CHECK_NUMBER"  },
                commit: { type: "DISPLAY_NUMBER" },
                rollback: { type: TYPES.CHECK_NUMBER, meta: { data } }
            }
        }
```

I want to fire the "CHECK_NUMBER" at the first place and get the result back to the commit part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that an action can't be fired in "meta.offline.effect". We can add an action to be fired in "meta.offline.commit" and "meta.offline.rollback". I used "redux-saga" to send calls to the API and get back the results and now my application is working in offline mode.

```
    ex: export const addCustomer = (data) => {
        return {
            type: TYPES.ADD_CUSTOMER,
            payload: { data },
            meta: {
                offline: {
                    effect: { },
                    commit: { type: "SUBMIT_CUSTOMER", meta: { data } },
                    rollback: { type: TYPES.SUBMIT_CUSTOMER, meta: { data } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In saga :

```
function* submitCustomer(action) {

    const data = { FirstName: action.meta.data };
    const result = yield axios.post(`https://localhost:44300/api/Values/SubmitCustomer`, data)
    .then(Response => Response).catch(error => {
        throw error
    });
}

function* customerSaga() {
    yield takeEvery("SUBMIT_CUSTOMER", submitCustomer);
}

export default customerSaga;
```